# @media only screen and (max-width:736px){ul{font-size:150%;}} not working in outlook ios app

Tags: css, media-queries

I've got about 10 `@media` queries in my newsletter's `<style>` tag and all work great with one exception. My

```
@media only screen and (max-width:736px) { ul{ font-size:150%; } }
```

does not work in the Outlook iOS app.

When viewing newsletters containing a list in the Outlook app on my iPhone, the list text is small and does not get resized like all the other text in the newsletter. Using this same code, the list text does get resized in the Gmail app, the Yahoo app and the Apple mail app.

Any idea why

```
@media only screen and (max-width:736px) {ul {font-size:150%; } }
```

does not work in the Outlook iOS app?

Comment: It may be that they disabled media query support again ?
https://litmus.com/blog/consistent-media-query-support-returning-to-outlook-apps
read the update. i dont know if this still is true

Comment: I don't think so as all my other media queries work in the Outlook iOS app.

Comment: I reported my issue to the outlook@litmus.com address listed in that blog.